# Why only a few ports (like ssh, http, https) are appeared to be open while all others are closed in nmap, on a host without firewall?

Tags: debian, networking, nmap

I have two Debian 11 machines (192.168.0.2 & 192.168.0.3) connected to the same router (gateway at 192.168.0.1). I have disabled firewall (`ufw`) of both. But when I did a port scan via `nmap` from 192.168.0.2 to 3 (`$ nmap 192.168.0.3`) I get only 22/tcp ssh open as follows

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-09-30 05:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.3
Host is up (0.000081s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.22 seconds
```

Shouldn't I get the result of every port being open, having the firewalls disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many questions explaining the difference between an open port in the firewall context and an open port in the `nmap` context.

In short: in the context of `nmap`, a port is open when there is a process listening to it. If you only have an ssh process listening, then only that port will be open.

I always compare it with counters. The "open" in terms of the firewall means that the "closed" sign is removed from the counter. The "open" in terms of `nmap` means, that there is an actual employee behind the cunter.

Comment: Not in short: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1673815/432690).